# How to correctly calibrate my camera with a wide angle lens using openCV?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am trying to calibrate a camera with a fisheye lens. I therefor used the fisheye lens module, but keep getting strange results no matter what distortion parameters I fix.
This is the input image I use: https://i.stack.imgur.com/abE5g.jpg

where the red circles indicate the corners I use to calibrate my camera.

This is the best I could get, output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV4fn.jpg

I currently don't know by heart what the camera sensor dimensions are, but based on the focal length in pixels that is being calculated in my nitrinsic matrix, I deduce my sensor size is approximately 3.3mm (assuming my physical focal length is 1.8mm), which seems realistic to me. Yet, when undistorting my input image I get nonsense. Could someone tell me what I may be doing incorrectly?

the matrices and rms being output by the calibration:

```
K:[263.7291703200009, 0, 395.1618975493187;
 0, 144.3800397321767, 188.9308218101271;
 0, 0, 1]

D:[0, 0, 0, 0]

rms: 9.27628
```

my code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/ccalib/omnidir.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

vector<vector<Point2d> > points2D;
vector<vector<Point3d> > objectPoints;

Mat src;

//so that I don't have to select them manually every time
void initializePoints2D()
{
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(234, 128));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(300, 124));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(381, 126));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(460, 127));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(529, 137));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(207, 147));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(280, 147));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(379, 146));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(478, 153));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(551, 165));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(175, 180));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(254, 182));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(377, 185));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(502, 191));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(586, 191));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(136, 223));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(216, 239));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(373, 253));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(534, 248));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(624, 239));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(97, 281));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(175, 322));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(370, 371));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(578, 339));
    points2D[0].push_back(Point2d(662, 298));


    for(int j=0; j<25;j++)
    {   
        circle(src, points2D[0].at(j), 5, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, 8, 0);
    }

    imshow("src with circles", src);
    waitKey(0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat srcSaved;

    src = imread("images/frontCar.png");
    resize(src, src, Size(), 0.5, 0.5);
    src.copyTo(srcSaved);

    vector<Point3d> objectPointsRow;
    vector<Point2d> points2DRow;
    objectPoints.push_back(objectPointsRow);
    points2D.push_back(points2DRow);

    for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
    {

        for(int j=0; j<5;j++)
        {
            objectPoints[0].push_back(Point3d(5*j,5*i,1));        
        }
    }

    initializePoints2D();
    cv::Matx33d K;
    cv::Vec4d D;
    std::vector<cv::Vec3d> rvec;
    std::vector<cv::Vec3d> tvec;


    int flag = 0;
    flag |= cv::fisheye::CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC;
    flag |= cv::fisheye::CALIB_CHECK_COND;
    flag |= cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_SKEW; 
    flag |= cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_K1; 
    flag |= cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_K2; 
    flag |= cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_K3; 
    flag |= cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_K4; 


    double rms =cv::fisheye::calibrate(
 objectPoints, points2D, src.size(), 
 K, D, rvec, tvec, flag, cv::TermCriteria(3, 20, 1e-6)     
 );

    Mat output;
    cerr<<"K:"<<K<<endl;
    cerr<<"D:"<<D<<endl;
    cv::fisheye::undistortImage(srcSaved, output, K, D);
    cerr<<"rms: "<<rms<<endl;
    imshow("output", output);
    waitKey(0);

    cerr<<"image .size: "<<srcSaved.size()<<endl;

}
```

If anybody has an idea, feel free to either share some code in Python either in C++. Whatever floats your boat.

**EDIT:**

As you may have notice I don't use a black and white checkerboard for the calibration, but corners from tiles constituting my carpet. At the end of the day the goal -I think- is to get corner coordinates which represent samples from the distortion radii . The carpet is to some extent the same as the checkerboard, the only difference -once again I think- is the fact that you have less high frequency edges at those eg corners on the carpet than on a black and white checkerboard.

I know the number of pictures is very limited, ie only 1. I expect the image to be undistorted to some extent, but I also expect the undistortion to be very well done. But in this case the image output looks like total nonsense.

I ended up using this image with a chessboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWTKJ.jpg
provided by this website: https://sites.google.com/site/scarabotix/ocamcalib-toolbox/ocamcalib-toolbox-download-page
But results are still very poor: diagonal lines like the other output image I posted.

Thanks

Comment: @privetDruzia the only thing I can think off, is to change the flags, and also the termCriteria (put more rounds, like 100).

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is that you are only using one image. Even if you had an ideal pinhole camera with no distortion, you would not be able to estimate the intrinsics from a single image of co-planar points. One image of co-planar points simply does not give you enough constraints to solve for the intrinsics.

You need at least two images at different 3D orientations, or a 3D calibration rig, where the points are not co-planar.  Of course, in practice you need at least 20 images for accurate calibration.

Your second problem is that you are using a carpet as the checkerboard. You need to be able to detect the points in the image with sub-pixel accuracy. Small localization errors result in large errors in the estimated camera parameters. I seriously doubt that you can detect the corners of the squares of your carpet with any reasonable accuracy. In fact, you cannot even measure the actual point locations on the carpet very accurately, because it is fuzzy.

Best of luck!

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, I ll look into that! Woud you mind elaborating on the sub-pixel accuracy? AFAIK the carpet's or checkerboard's corners are being detected in the image space by eg a harris corner detector, Whcih means that the locations in pixels of the corners returned by this function are integer values.

Comment: I ended up using this image with a chessboard: https://imgur.com/a/WlLBR

Which I found on this website: https://sites.google.com/site/scarabotix/ocamcalib-toolbox/ocamcalib-toolbox-download-page

But results are still very poor: diagonal lines like the other output image I posted.

Comment: @privetDruzia, yes, the Harris algorithm by itself gives you corners at integer coordinates. Then you take the pixel neighborhood centered at the corner, and fit a 2D quadratic function to the Harris function in that neighborhood. Then you compute the minimum of the paraboloid, and use that as the refined location of the corner.  Most functions that do interest point detection will do that for you.

Comment: @privetDruzia When you used the chessboard image, did you still only use one image? Not to mention that you need to take images with your own camera, if that's what you want to calibrate.

Comment: I managed to undistort my image using only 1 image without a chessboard :). This input: https://imgur.com/a/ZmpmX gave me this output: https://imgur.com/a/ZmpmX

I now have an almost undistorted carpet. I might get better results by using more images, with eg a checkerboard a bit everywhere, but this is much closer to what I expected. What do you *honnestly* think about it?

Comment: I think you posted the same link twice.  Also irrespective of what I think about your results, you cannot calibrate with just one image of planar points.