# camera calibration - unable to detect chessboard

Tags: python, c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I am using openCV's function to detect a chessboard, yet no chessboard is being detected.

The image I am using:

[image]

```
const Size chessboardDimensions = Size(4,8);
int main (int argv, char ** argc)
{
        frame = imread("/home/Georges/Desktop/a.jpg");
        cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        int found = findChessboardCorners(frame, chessboardDimensions, foundPoints, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);

}
```

found always equals 0. Could someone explain me why?

Comment: found should be a bool not an int, it tells you if the pattern was found (I think it will return the corners found even if it returns false). In you case the size is wrong, thus it cannot find the pattern.

Comment: @api55 Hi, I d like to post my question here as a comment because I saw that OP is using an image which is the same as the one I used. As the topic of my question is very specific, I am affraid it won't get a lot of attention. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46225943/how-to-correctly-calibrate-my-camera-with-a-wide-angle-lens-using-opencv/

Any idea's about the issue I am facing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const Size chessboardDimensions = Size(4,8);
```

In this expression size should be

```
Size(5,8)
```

Because you should count inner squares's corners.

Edit:

As mentioned in comments, `int found` should be `bool`. Because the function returns if corners are found or not.

And as suggestion add fast checking option to your function otherwise the function may work laggy:

```
bool found = findChessboardCorners(frame, chessboardDimensions, foundPoints, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE | CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);
```

And it is good idea to check if all points found correctly. In some cases all points cannot be detected and in further applications this situation gives an error. Because the output of this function will be input of another one. So add an continue expression to your loop:

```
if(found == 0 || foundPoints.size() != chessboardDimensions.area())
    continue;
```

Comment: Such stupid typo! I ll accept your answer in a few minutes.