# FindChessboardCorners cannot detect chessboard on very large images by long focal length lens

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I can use FindChessboardCorners functions for images that less than 15 Mega pixel such like 2k x 1.5k. however when I use it on the image from DSLR, the resolution at 3700x5300, it doesn't work.

I tried to use resize() to reduce the image size directly, then it works.

Obviously there's some hard coded or bug in the OpenCV source code.

Could you help me to figure it out, or point me to a patch for this ?

I found someone posted a similar issue in 2006, [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/41563), so it looks like the problem still remains.

The code I used is like

```
found = findChessboardCorners( viewGray, boardSize, ptvec,
                                CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS + CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + CV_CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);
```

**Update**

Just here to clarify. I think the algorithm works on large image resolution, but it fails when the chessboard occupy larger proportion of the image. 
For example, when I use a 50mm fixed lens on the same camera position, FindChessboardCorners never fails. After I change it to 100mm fixed lens, the function starts to stop detecting the pattern. I think it relates to the proportion or the focal length.

The image below is the 100mm lens result.

**Update 2**

I added a sharpen filter to the large image, and it starts to fix the problem.

Firstly I used

```
//do a sharpen filter for the large resolution image
if (viewGray.cols > 1500)
{
  Mat temp ;
  GaussianBlur(viewGray,temp, Size(0,0), 105) ; //hardcoded filter size, to be tested on 50 mm lens
  addWeighted(viewGray, 1.8, temp, -0.8,0,viewGray) ; //hardcoded weight, to be tested.
//imwrite("test"+ imageList[k][i], viewGray) ;

}

found = findChessboardCorners( viewGray, boardSize, ptvec,
CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS + CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + CV_CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);
```

**Uploaded the image:**

A jpg image at original resolution 3744 x 5616, if this site force convert, then make sure you are using at the correct resolution.

[image: A jpg image at original resolution 3744 x 5616, if this site force convert, then make sure you are using at the correct resolution.]

Comment: Could you upload the image? Also, does it crash or it just returns false?

Comment: @Chrys, uploaded the image

Comment: could it be a problem with the image? what kind of f-stop do you use? maybe low depth of field might confuse the algorithm? look at the bottom right corner it is a bit blurry right?

Comment: @Alex, but it doesn't explain why it works when you resize it to half.

Comment: @Alex, OK, I think I should try a sharpen filter.

Comment: If you are interested in _calibrating your camera_, not necessarily  _detecting a chessboard_, there are other solutions like [ProCamCalib](http://www.ok.ctrl.titech.ac.jp/~saudet/research/procamcalib/) that should work more reliably.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A few points.

1. Down-sizing, as you noticed, helps the detector. That is because the corner-detection filters used in OpenCV to find the corners have fixed size, and that size of convolution mask may be too small to detect your corners - the full-size image may actually look "smooth" at that scale, particularly where it is slightly blurry. However, by downscaling you throw away some corner location accuracy.
2. For the same reason, sharpening helps too. However, it also goes against accuracy, because it adds bias to the subpixel positions of the corners - even in the ideal case with no noise. To convince yourself that this is the case, consider the 1D analogue: the intensity of the image around a corner (in 1D, a sharp black-white transition) looks ideally like a sigmoid curve (a ramp with smooth corners), and you want to find the location of its inflection point. Sharpening makes the curve steeper, which in general will move that point's location. Things get worse when you take into account that sharpening generally amplifies noise.
3. The likely correct way to proceed is to start at a lower resolution (i.e. downsizing), then scale up the positions of the corners thus found, and use them as the initial estimates for a run of cvFindCornersSubpix at full resolution.

Comment: You are welcome. I also noticed in your picture that the target seems to have been glued on some kind or foam or baseboard support. I warmly recommend using something more rigid and flat - especially if you want to take advantage of the full resolution of a modern DSLR sensor. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794876/how-to-verify-the-correctness-of-calibration-of-a-webcam

Comment: it's a special baseboard similar with foam, but I think it's pretty flat. I tried your suggestion point 3, and it has the same effect as a sharpen filter, but I think I choose your method because it would make the findchessboardcorner faster at lower res, which is vital for high res image. The problem is the 100mm fixed focal lens I use, the depth of field on this lens is too short which generates lots of blur, I would try to use smaller iris and see if it improves.

Comment: Down-sizing ok, but what is the good size ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the OpenCV source and can rebuild it, then maybe you can debug the behavior of `cvFindChessboardCorners`.

You have to `#define` `DEBUG_CHESSBOARD` and then you will have some helps in understanding the algorithm.

I think OpenCV 2.4 has this capability (see for example https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/calib3d/src/calibinit.cpp).

Furthermore, even if it doesn't seem to apply to your case, OpenCV doc gives a requirement for the calibration target:

> **Note**: The function requires white space (like a square-thick border, the wider the better) around the board to make the detection
>   more robust in various environments. Otherwise, if there is no border
>   and the background is dark, the outer black squares cannot be
>   segmented properly and so the square grouping and ordering algorithm
>   fails.

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findchessboardcorners

The chessboard in the question has an even number of inner corner both for rows (6 corners) and columns (8 corners) while a [reference OpenCV chessboard](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/pattern.png) [image]has an even/odd number of corners, i.e. it is 9x6, I do not know wether this can be a problem.

Comment: It does have a white border around the chessboard. My advice here is to use the calibration sample at https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/calibration.cpp . It will tell you when corners are found. I modify the if(found){...drawChessboardCorners(...);} and included an else-block that just cout-s when corners are not found so that I can keep track on the images in a more decent fashion.