# Decompose Homography matrix in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

H = K[R|t]
where H (3*3) is homographic matrix, R is Rotation matrix, K is matrix of camera's intrinsic parameters and t is translation vector.

I have calculated K using chess board pattern as follows

```
ret, K, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, chess_gray.shape[::-1],None,None)
```

Homograpy matrix H is calculated as

```
pts_src = np.float32(pts_src)
pts_dst = np.float32(pts_dst)
H, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)
```

How to decompose R and t from H and K using

```
cv2.decomposeHomograpyMat(H,K,....)
```

How to write other inputs and outputs of above functions?

Comment: Is this different from the Kabsch Algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm)?

Comment: Thank you for ur comment. I have seen this , It calculates R from multiple 3D points, but I want to estimate R from H.  I have seen one Homograpy decomposition method for finding R. But  I want opencv python implementation.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are looking out for but [THIS POST](http://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/) might give a little insight

Comment: Actually, I want one step ahead of post u mentioned .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming H as homography matrix and K as camera matrix the Python code is:

```
num, Rs, Ts, Ns  = cv2.decomposeHomographyMat(H, K)
```

*num* possible solutions will be returned.

Rs contains a list of the rotation matrix.
Ts contains a list of the translation vector.
Ns contains a list of the normal vector of the plane.

For further informations take a look into the official documentation:
[OpenCV 3.4 - decomposeHomographyMat()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga7f60bdff78833d1e3fd6d9d0fd538d92)

Comment: What about if I don't know anything about the matrix camera K. What would be a "generic" matrix to use?