# Determine appropriate size of calibration board for camera calibration

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

How does one determine the appropriate physical size of calibration board for camera calibration ? In the past, I have used ones like [these](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/htmls/pattern.pdf) printed on A4 size paper.   Reasonable criteria seem to be the precision(i.e. how accurate) and completeness(i.e. are all corners detected) with a particular sized board. But, short of printing multiple sizes and trying them all, is there any other approach ?

On a related note, if we know that the "depth of field" of interest is 2 metres to 2.5 metres from the camera, would it be better to use the calibration pattern within this range or would it be better to try it ignoring such preferences ?

Answer (score 2):

it is a wrong question to ask. Apart from resolution of the board that is going to be probably fine for a wide range of sizes the important question is how many boards you have to show to your camera in order to find accurately intrinsic and extrinsic parameters.

Unlike PnP or posit or extrinsic problem calibration has to find both extrinsic and intrinsic. You will have to cover camera whole field of view with images of your board plus (or rather times) different board orientations and distances. This is because converging to the right intrinsic and extrinsic requires seeing vanishing points while eliminating a bias in pixel error metrics requires uniform sampling of the field of view.

Comment: It occurred to me that we could examine the reprojection errors for the intrinisics and extrinisic variables and use the set of images/board sizes for which these seem lowest. Short of this "exhaustive"(no pun intended) search, I wanted to know if there is a better method.

Comment: Nope, sorry. You can have a very little reprojeciton error and very wrong parameters. Try a reproduction error of a single image of a small chess board to see this, for example.

Comment: In your original answer, you mention covering camera's field of view and the board's orientations and distances. There is no mention of board size. Surely it cannot be the case that there is somehow a one-size-fits-all board. I would think that have a board with larger squares/more squares would change things as well.

Comment: The size of squares cannot be too small since it will interfere with fi ding a correct order of corners in oblique views of a board. Subpixel corner algorithm also requires a curtain size window around a corner. The size of of the board determi es the number of shots you have to make to cover the field of view given viewing distance.

Answer (score 1):

First, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794876/how-to-verify-the-correctness-of-calibration-of-a-webcam/12821056#12821056) for general notes on manufacturing a calibration target.

Doing a complete sensitivity analysis is quite complicate. A rule of thumb I have used is to assume that my corner detector is accurate up to 1/2 a pixel worst case. Then, given an approximate field of view (which you can estimate from the lens's nominal focal length in mm and the width of the sensor chip), and a specification for the min and max distance used in the application, I worked out the sensitivity of a plane's estimated pose in various orientations and positions in the calibration volume, given a worst case error in its four corners. I then played with its size until the worst case error became acceptable - and within my budget and the other application constraints (weight, depth of field, resolution, etc).