# Different planes during Camera Calibration

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am using standard OpenCV functions to calibrate camera for intrinsic parameters. In order to obtain good results, I know we have to use images of the chessboard from different angles (considering different planes in the 3D). This is stated in all the documentations
and papers but I really don't understand, why is it so important for us to consider different planes and if there is an optimal number of planes that we have to consider for the best calibration results?

I will be glad if you can provide me reference to some paper or documentation which explains this. (I think Zhang's paper talks about it but, its mathematically intensive and was hart to digest.)

Thanks

Comment: Try the camera calibrator app in MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/single-camera-calibrator-app.html

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, a unique solution for the intrinsic parameters (up to scale) is defined only if you have 3 or more distinct images of the planar target. See page 6 of Zhang's [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zhang/Papers/TR98-71.pdf): "If n images of the model plane are observed, by stacking n such equations as (8) we have Vb = 0 ; (9) where V is a 2n×6 matrix. If n ≥ 3, we will have in general a unique solution b deﬁned up to a scale factor..."

There isn't an "optimal" number of planes, where data are concerned, the more you have the merrier you are. But as the solution starts to converge, the marginal gain in calibration accuracy due to adding an extra image becomes negligible. Of course, this assumes that the images show planes well separated in both pose and location.

See also [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794876/how-to-verify-the-correctness-of-calibration-of-a-webcam?rq=1) for practical tips.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a little intuition, here's an example of why one plane isn't enough. Imagine your calibration chessboard is tilting away from you at a 45° angle:
[image: chess board at 45 degrees]

You can see that when you move up the chessboard by 1 meter in the +y direction, you also move away from the camera by 1 meter in the +z direction. This means there's no way to separate the effect of moving in the y direction vs the z direction. The y and z movement directions are effectively tied to each other, for all our training points. So, if we just look at points on this one plane, there's no way to tease apart the effects of y movement vs z movement.

For example, from this 1 plane, we can't tell the difference between these scenarios:

1. The camera has perspective distortion such that things appear smaller in the image as they move in the world's +y direction.
2. The camera focal length is such that things appear smaller in the image as they move in the world's +z direction.
3. Any mixture of the effects in #1 and #2.

Mathematically, this ambiguity means that there are many equally possible solutions when OpenCV tries to fit a camera matrix to match the data. (Note that the 45° angle was not important. Any plane you choose will have the same problem: training examples' (x,y,z) dimensions are coupled together, so you can't separate their effects.)

One last note: if you make enough assumptions about the camera matrix (e.g. no perspective distortion, x and y scale identically, etc) then you can end up with a situation with fewer unknowns (in an extreme case, maybe you're just calculating the focal length) and in that case you could calibrate with just 1 plane.