# Selecting views of chessboard in camera calibration

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I am using 20 views of chessboard  to calibrate camera and rectify images.I have tried changing images , and every time  different rectified images were obtained(by changing views).
I have been trying for many days but the images obtained are  tilted and disparity map consists of a lot error pixels. How to fix it?

I am using python-opencv.
[image: I have obtained image like that:]

Comment: The images obtained are like that perspective transform is applied on them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the calibration you obtain is correct? See the advice at the bottom of [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794876/how-to-verify-the-correctness-of-calibration-of-a-webcam/12821056#12821056) for tips on how to do it.

Comment: I read this before! I am doing the same thing Martin Peris did for calibrating his camera.http://blog.martinperis.com/2011/08/stereo-vision-why-camera-calibration-is.html. It seems like it will get fixed at a particular set of images, the different images I take, different results are produced.Hope that it get fixed soon!

Comment: Even the unrectified images seem to be better than the rectified ones.

Comment: Have you any idea that is this the part of rectification process? (obtaining perspective transform of images, and then they get better)