# Calibrate camera with opencv, how does it work and how do i have to move my chessboard

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I'm using openCV the calibrateCamera function to calibrate my camera. I started from the tutorial [implementation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html), but there seems something wrong.

The camera is looking down on a table and i use a chessboard with an area that covers about 1/2 or 1/4 of my total image. Since I aim to track a flat object that slides over this table, I also slide my chessboard over this table.

So my first question is: is it ok that i move my chessboard over this table? Or do I have to make some 3D movements in order to get some good result?
Because I was wondering: how does the function guesses the distance between the table and the camera? He has only a guess of his focal point, and he has only one "eye", so there is no depth vision.

My second question: how does the bloody thing work? :p Can anyone show me some implementation of this function?

Thx!

Comment: I would also love to know that. There's a lot of API explained in OpenCV, but not what you're actually supposed to do pysically.

Answer (score 4):

the camera calibration needs a seed of points to calculate the camera matrix and the the position of the central point of the camera, and the distortion matrices , if you want to use a chessboard you have to take in consideration its dimension(I never used the circles function because  the detection of chessboard is easier ) , the dimension of the chessboard should be  pair X unpair  number so you can get a correct rotation matrix ! the calibration function needs minimum 8x set of chessboardCorners and ( I use 30 tell 50) it depends on how precise you want to be .the return value of the calibration function is the re-projection error this should be near to zero if the calibration is good.
the cameraCalibration take a the size of used chessboards ( you can use different chessboardSize) and the dimension ( in mm or cm or even m etc.. ) your result will depend on your given dimension.
By the way after getting the chessboardCorners you have to refines them with the function `CornerSubPix` you can set how good the refinement is in the function parameter.

In the internet you can find a lot docs about this subject.

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~majumder/vispercep/cameracalib.pdf

I hope it helps !

Comment: I already understand the working principle of this function, but I wanted to know the calculations behind it.


Assume that the chessboard is 7x7 and every square has a dimension of 2x2cm. How does the method estimates the distance from camera to the chessboard? Because if the chessboard is far away from the cam but the cam has a huge zoom lens, the image will be the same as it was held closeby with a normal lens.

The only way i see to get a better estimate, is to have some images were the chessboard is tilted a bit... Or is there something else i don't see?

Comment: There are lots of articles regarding this subject. Also, numerous questions are asked in stackoverflow. If you take a look at O'Reily's OpenCV book (or any appropriate book), you would understand the working principle of the concept.

Answer (score 1):

regarding the chessboard positions, I got best results with 25-30 images
First I do 3 -4 images that show the chessboard at different distances full frame half 1/3 1/4
then I make sure to go to each corner, each center of each edge plus 4 rotation on each axis XYZ. When using a 640x480 sensor my reprojection error was mostly around 0.1 or even better

here a few links that got me in the right direction:
[How to verify the correctness of calibration of a webcam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794876/how-to-verify-the-correctness-of-calibration-of-a-webcam)

Comment: I've heard that placing the chessboard on a parallel plane to the image plane (camera looking straight forwards at it) introduces calibration errors.