# How the checkerboard size affect an accurate Camera Calibration?

Tags: image-processing, camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration, calibration

- Right now, I am calibrating a monocular camera so afterwards I can calculate distance of planar objects in the image (Z=0).

However, I'd like to know how much it is important to know the structure size. The board's squares sizes change a lot in the image based on how far you are so I am not sure if it is a robust parameter as you would always have a relative scale?

Moreover, for my camera which will be mounted on a ceiling (around 10 meters high), how could I estimate suitable sizes of a checkerboard and squares for accurate calibration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic rule of thumb is that the checkerboard should be in focus, approximately fill the field of view in some of the images, and be significantly slanted in some other images. It helps if you have a finite volume of space you work with, and you span most of it with measurements. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794876/how-to-verify-the-correctness-of-calibration-of-a-webcam/12821056#12821056) for more.