# Drawing checkerboard's reference frame for pose estimation using OpenCV (solvePnP+projectPoints)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have followed the tutorial at https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d53/tutorial_py_pose.html based on calibration data obtained following the tutorial at https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html.

The end objective is to obtain the pose of the checkerboard with respect to the camera, but first I am trying to draw the checkerboard's reference frame.

The input data is a set of 2 snapshots I have taken of my webcam feed pointed at a printed 10x7 checkerboard.

The calibration seems to succeed:
[image]
[image]
But the output is totally wrong:
[image]
[image]
Here is the patched-up code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import glob
import argparse

# algorithm parameters
CHECKERBOARD_WIDTH = 9
CHECKERBOARD_HEIGHT = 6


# termination criteria
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

#=== CALIBRATE CAMERA ============================================================================

#Prepare object points
objp = np.zeros((CHECKERBOARD_HEIGHT * CHECKERBOARD_WIDTH, 3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:CHECKERBOARD_HEIGHT, 0:CHECKERBOARD_WIDTH].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

# Load the images
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-f', '--folder', required=True,  help='Path to the images folder with last slash')
ap.add_argument('-e', '--ext', required=True,  help='Extension of image files without the dot')
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

images = glob.glob(args['folder']+'*.'+args['ext'])

#Process the images
for fname in images:
    print('Calibrating on '+fname)
    img = cv.imread(fname)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv.findChessboardCorners(gray, (CHECKERBOARD_WIDTH,CHECKERBOARD_HEIGHT), None)
    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        print('Found corners')
        objpoints.append(objp)
        corners2 = cv.cornerSubPix(gray,corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners)
        # Draw and display the corners as feedback to the user
        cv.drawChessboardCorners(img, (CHECKERBOARD_WIDTH,CHECKERBOARD_HEIGHT), corners2, ret)
        cv.imshow('Calibration', img)
        k = cv.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
        if k == ord('s'):
            cv.imwrite(fname+'_calib.png', img)

cv.destroyAllWindows()

#Obtain camera parameters
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)

#=== FIND POSE OF TARGETS ===========================================================================

#Prepare object points
objp = np.zeros((CHECKERBOARD_HEIGHT * CHECKERBOARD_WIDTH, 3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:CHECKERBOARD_HEIGHT, 0:CHECKERBOARD_WIDTH].T.reshape(-1,2)

axis = np.float32([[3,0,0], [0,3,0], [0,0,-3]]).reshape(-1,3)

#Display 
def draw(img, corners, imgpts):
    corner = tuple(corners[0].ravel())
    img = cv.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[0].ravel()), (255,0,0), 5)
    img = cv.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[1].ravel()), (0,255,0), 5)
    img = cv.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[2].ravel()), (0,0,255), 5)
    return img

for fname in images:
    print('Processing '+fname)
    img = cv.imread(fname)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, corners = cv.findChessboardCorners(gray, (CHECKERBOARD_WIDTH,CHECKERBOARD_HEIGHT), None)
    if ret == True:
        print('Found corners')
        corners2 = cv.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        # Find the rotation and translation vectors.
        ret,rvecs, tvecs = cv.solvePnP(objp, corners2, mtx, dist)
        # project 3D points to image plane
        imgpts, jac = cv.projectPoints(axis, rvecs, tvecs, mtx, dist)
        img = draw(img,corners2,imgpts)
        cv.imshow('img',img)
        k = cv.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
        if k == ord('s'):
            cv.imwrite(fname+'_output.png', img)

cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Called e.g. with:

```
python3 test_cvpnp.py --folder ./images/ --ext png
```

The images for calibration and for the processing are the same, which should yield good results. What is happening?

The original images are as follows, in case you might want to reproduce the behaviour:
[image]
[image]

**Edit:** *I have tested opening my webcam frame-by-frame and processing 30-40 frames (at 2 FPS) in different orientations instead of 2 to get more data, but the reference frames are still drawn completely incorrectly and **the RMS error for calibration is ~100 apparently**. The improved code can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ryLlOJcaMeIiaGWSxmpyDwCOeHdYWUun/view?usp=sharing). What's wrong?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a long, long, long time comparing my code with an example as-is formatted in the same way, to finally notice I had swapped Width and Height when calling findChessboardCorners()... Problem solved, everything works as expected with an RMS error between 0.2 and 0.6. The pose of the target is very accurately tracked, so I can confirm we do not need expensive targets to have sub-pixel RMS accuracy.

Comment: Correct, but you do need accurate targets (generally, apparatus) to reliably translate sub-pixel RMS errors into physically accurate measurements. As is usually the case, you get what you pay for and there is no free lunch.

Comment: I wasn't saying otherwise. I said such a setup was sufficient for first order measurements - which having finished the whole system seems to back up. For those reading who might be wrongly discouraged when their goal is actually achievable this way.

Comment: Absolutely: if one's goal to is to learn about camera geometry calibration, get an intuition for the problems, or even work with an application where projection errors of a one-few pixels are acceptable, a low cost setup is all that's needed.  It's going beyond that that requires work on often money.

Answer (score 1):

Getting 100 pixel RMS error means your calibration is very wrong.

Your images show a target that is not very flat, and some blurring.

Suggest you follow [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12821056/1435240).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, at least I have confirmation the calibration is wrong. However I have a big target and it's taped tightly to the back of a laptop, and the chessboard corners are detected very accurately - or accurately enough: I am not looking for sub degree or millimeter accuracy, 10°, 1 square accuracy would be fine. I cannot conceive this can't be reached, there must be something wrong with the code.Especially given that the hardware used in the tutorial is not that far off what I have, and it works great apparently!