# Image rectification for depth perception is not correct

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d, stereoscopy

I am struggling a lot trying to write code to rectify two images. I'm hoping to calculate depth and then pull out a point cloud. I can't calculate depth because I can't rectify my images and calculate a disparity map.

These are my functions to calibrate my cameras and rectify the stereo images

```
def CamIntr(image_paths, chessboard_params, square_size):
    # Calibration chessboard parameters
    #chessboard_params = [6, 9]  # Number of corners in y, x
    chessboard_params.append(square_size)  # Square size in m
    num_corners = chessboard_params[0] * chessboard_params[1]

    # Termination criteria for corner refinement
    criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

    # Prepare object points (world coordinates)
    objp = np.zeros((chessboard_params[0] * chessboard_params[1], 3), np.float32)
    objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:chessboard_params[0], 0:chessboard_params[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2)*chessboard_params[2]

    # Arrays to store object points and image points from all images
    objpoints = []  # 3D points in real-world space
    imgpoints = []  # 2D points in image plane

    for path in image_paths:
        # Read the image
        image = cv.imread(path)
        gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Convert to grayscale

        # Find chessboard corners
        ret, corners = cv.findChessboardCorners(gray, (chessboard_params[0], chessboard_params[1]), None)

        
        #print(f"Chessboard found in {path}")
        objpoints.append(objp)
        corners2 = cv.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)
        # Draw and display the corners
        #cv.drawChessboardCorners(image, (chessboard_params[1], chessboard_params[0]), corners2, ret)
        #cv.imshow('img', image)
        #cv.imwrite("Chessboard_draw.jpg", image) 
        #cv.waitKey(500)
      
    
    ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
    
    
    return ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs, objpoints, imgpoints 



def RectifyStereoImages(img_left, img_right, chessboardL, chessboardR):
    # Load stereo calibration data (intrinsics, extrinsics, etc.)
    
    gray_left = cv.imread(img_left,0)
    gray_right = cv.imread(img_right,0)
    
    ##CALIBRATION
    
    _, mtx_left, dist_left, rvecs_left, tvecs_left, objpoints_left, imgpoints_left = CamIntr(chessboardL, [6,9], 0.025)


    _, mtx_right, dist_right, rvecs_right, tvecs_right, objpoints_right, imgpoints_right = CamIntr(chessboardR, [6,9], 0.025)

    

   ##STEREO VISION CALIBRATION
   
    _, _, _, _, _, R, T, E, F = cv.stereoCalibrate(objpoints_left, imgpoints_left, imgpoints_right,
                                                    mtx_left, dist_left, mtx_right, dist_right,
                                                    gray_left.shape[::-1], criteria=(cv.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC, 30, 0.001))
    
    flags = 0
    flags |= cv.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC
    # Here we fix the intrinsic camara matrixes so that only Rot, Trns, Emat and Fmat are calculated.
    # Hence intrinsic parameters are the same 
    
    criteria_stereo= (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
    
    # This step is performed to transformation between the two cameras and calculate Essential and Fundamenatl matrix
    retStereo, newCameraMatrixL, distL, newCameraMatrixR, distR, rot, trans, essentialMatrix, fundamentalMatrix = cv.stereoCalibrate(objpoints_left, imgpoints_left, imgpoints_right, mtx_left, dist_left, mtx_right, dist_right, gray_left.shape[::-1], criteria_stereo, flags)
    
    ##STEREO RECTIFICATION

    rectifyScale= 1
    rectL, rectR, projMatrixL, projMatrixR, Q, roi_L, roi_R= cv.stereoRectify(newCameraMatrixL, distL, newCameraMatrixR, distR, gray_left.shape[::-1], rot, trans, rectifyScale,(0,0), alpha = 0.5)
    
    stereoMapL = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx_left, distL, rectL, projMatrixL, gray_left.shape[::-1], cv.CV_16SC2)
    stereoMapR = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx_right, distR, rectR, projMatrixR, gray_right.shape[::-1], cv.CV_16SC2)
    
    map_left_x = stereoMapL[0]
    map_left_y = stereoMapL[1]
    map_right_x = stereoMapR[0]
    map_right_y = stereoMapR[1]
    
    # Rectify the images
    img_left_rectified = cv.remap(gray_left, map_left_x, map_left_y, cv.INTER_LANCZOS4, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, 0)
    img_right_rectified = cv.remap(gray_right, map_right_x, map_right_y, cv.INTER_LANCZOS4, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, 0)
    
    
    return img_left_rectified, img_right_rectified
```

And this is how I call it all.

```
# Get all files in the directory
all_files = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\emmay\Desktop\Folder")
# Filter files starting with the prefix "Chessboard"
chessboard1 = [file for file in all_files if file.startswith("Chessboard1")]
chessboard2 = [file for file in all_files if file.startswith("Chessboard2")]
squaresize = 0.025

img1 = "Chessboard1_1.png"
img2 = "Chessboard2_1.png"


imgL = cv.imread(img1,0)
imgR = cv.imread(img2,0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(imgL)
plt.show()
ax.set_title("Left original image")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(imgR)
plt.show()
ax.set_title("Right original image")

L_rect, R_rect = RectifyStereoImages(img1, img2, chessboard1, chessboard2)
#images after rectification
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(L_rect)
plt.show()
ax.set_title("Left rectified image")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(R_rect)
plt.show()
ax.set_title("Right rectified image")
```

I have 10 chessboard images from each camera, taken simultaneously. Do I calibrate each camera individually, even though they're the same camera? I have the images separated, just incase, but I have better results with image rectification if I pool them all together to get the camera intrinsics. When I separate the images I get different camera intrinsics and distortion variables, even though they're the same camera. For ease I am trying to rectify one of my chessboard images.

These are the images I'm trying to rectify:
[image]
[image]

This is my camera matrix and distortion coefficients for the first camera

```
array([[553.76951265,   0.        , 359.52945636],
       [  0.        , 558.7809926 , 322.92191203],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ]])

array([[-5.74144340e-01,  2.21330577e+00,  2.87945868e-03,
         9.47036694e-04, -3.28003833e+00]])
```

for the second camera

```
([[643.44291723,   0.        , 297.31281198],
       [  0.        , 639.47052736, 216.32413232],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ]])

array([[ 0.16309873, -1.99119008, -0.02374205, -0.01189547, 10.39937883]])
```

And then when I try to see the rectified image this is what I see:
[image]

If I try to find the camera intrinsics with all the pictures and don't separate them by left or right camera like this (forcing the intrinsics to be identical):

```
_, mtx_left, dist_left, rvecs_left, tvecs_left, objpoints_left, imgpoints_left = CamIntr(chessboardL + chessboardR, [6,9], 0.025)


    _, mtx_right, dist_right, rvecs_right, tvecs_right, objpoints_right, imgpoints_right = CamIntr(chessboardR, chessboardL, [6,9], 0.025)
```

I get this slightly better picture, but they're too different from each other now to calculate a disparity map

Does anyone know what's going on or could help me?

[image]

Comment: Basic debugging skills, check every step along the way: e.g. does `cv.findChessboardCorners` find the corners correctly to start? Also [ask] and [mre].

Comment: You definitely need to calibrate you cameras separately, they may be of the same model, but no 2 lenses are exactly the same, nor aligned at single pixel precision level...

Comment: I just checked that all the chessboard corners are identified correctly. I have 5 for each camera!

Comment: 5 corners is way too few. Recommend you take a look at this other answer of mine about  calibration procedure. Without good camera calibration metrically accurate stereo reconstruction is hopeless.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12821056/1435240

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct, and should be able to achieve what you want. The issues arise from methodology. Some important points:

- Generally you would always do separate calibrations of intrinsics as even two cameras of the same type have slight differences in lens alignment, distortion, etc. However, you do not necessarily have to do intrinics calibration (cv.calibrateCamera) before stereo calibration (cv.stereoCalibrate). OpenCV docs recommend it though for best robustness and maximum utilization of data if not all points were seen in all cameras.
- You cannot expect good results with handheld calibration targets. Camera synchronization must be impeccable for this to work, i.e. validated hardware triggered cameras.
- The size of your calibration target should ideally be such that it covers the entire image. Coded targets (i.e. ChArUco) can be useful to ensure detection when boards are only partly visible.
- The entire sensor should be covered by observations. You also need to observe foreshortening for proper f and cx, cy estimation.
- 5 images of each camera is likely not enough to estimate all parameters with sufficient accuracy.
- I recommend calling the extended variant of OpenCV's calibration functions, which provide you with standard errors on the estimated parameters. In a good calibration, these errors should be small compared to the parameter value.
- If only few images can be taken, it is advisable to fix as many parameters as possible. Your computed values for the distortion parameters are clearly wrong (much too large). For your lens, using only k1 is likely sufficient. Principle point coordinates should also be fixed to be the image center in these cases.

There are more tips and best practices here (I am the author of those): https://calib.io/blogs/knowledge-base/calibration-best-practices
A convenient tool for generating ChArUco pdf patterns can be found here: https://calib.io/pages/camera-calibration-pattern-generator